# Class 'Tymon\\JWTAuth\\Providers\\LaravelServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am getting error

> Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider' not found

what i did to solve :-

1. install `"tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-beta.3"`
2. then update the alias `'JWTAuth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class, 'JWTFactory' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory::class,`
3. set provider to `Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class,`
   but still getting error:

> Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider' not found
>   when usiing laravel 5.5

But still not working.

So what i need to do? Please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

A little old, but I thought I'd chime in. I was having the exact same problem the other day. I kept trying to run a migration and I would get a similar error. I swear I tried everything found in [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/class-tymonjwtauthprovidersjwtauthserviceprovider-not-found) post, but it didn't work. I managed to fix my issue by running these commands:

`composer update` (to make sure I had the latest packages), and
`composer install`

Then, I ran my migration. No errors after that. Funny thing is, I swear I did all this before. Maybe I did it in the wrong order. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, `composer dump-autoload` came to the rescue